# How to show 2 different class li.active at the same time?

Tags: jquery

In a menu im trying to style the main-level differently from the sub-level with Jquery, but pressing the sub-menu makes class active disappear from main-level?

I just dont get it - can someone explain why? Heres some basic code:

```
<ul class="vertic">  
  <li><a href="#">items</a>
      <ul class="show">
          <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Link 3</a></li>
      </ul> 
  </li>
</ul> 

// ACTIVE-CLASS on MAIN 
$('ul.vertic li a').click(function() {
    $("ul.vertic li a.active_main").removeClass("active_main");
    $(this).addClass('active_main');
    $(".show").show(100); 
});

// ACTIVE-CLASS on SUB 
$('ul.vertic li ul.show li a').click(function() {
    $("ul.vertic li ul li a.active_sub").removeClass("active_sub");
    $(this).addClass('active_sub'); 
});

nav ul li a.active_main  {
    border-bottom: 4px solid red;
    width: 100%;
    color: red;
}
nav ul.vertic li ul li a.active_sub {
    border-bottom: 4px solid green;
    width: 100%;
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: _“I just dont get it”_ – well then do some _debugging_ … log what event handlers get triggered to console, _look_ at what is actually happening in the DOM inspector, etc.

Comment: CBroe that answer didnt explain anything - why post it??

Comment: Here is the Jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NayUa/
but not able to find why the classes are not appearing.

Comment: First of all, it’s not an answer, it’s a comment. Second of all, what kind of debug measures have you attempted already? SO is not a “fix my code” site – foremost it is _your_ responsibility to debug and fix your code, and I gave you suggestions on how to start. So please tell us what you made of those.

Comment: You are right - code posted do contain errors - comes out of larger context - should have tested before posting. However seems like the code represents the topic well enough to be understood by others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this :

```
$('ul.vertic > li > a').click(function() {    
    $("ul.vertic > li > a.active_main").removeClass("active_main");
    $(this).addClass('active_main');
    $(".show").show(100); 
});
```

Comment: Pascatz - that is what i am looking for - i still dont understand why removeClass on sub seems to remove the class for main as well..

Comment: Because a click on an `a` element that is matched by the selector `ul.vertic li ul.show li a` triggers the click handler assigned to `ul.vertic li a` as well, since that selector matches the same `a` element as well.